# Primary ideal definition ambiguity

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I've been looking through most of the posts about definitions of primary ideals but something just doesn't click for me. Atiyah defines a primary ideal $q$ as follows
$$xy\in q\implies\text{either } x\in q \text{ or }y^n\in q \text{ for some }n>0.$$
Also, the example is given that all primary ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $(p^n)$ where $p$ is a prime number. So I think of a random number $p^np^{n+1}$. It's in $(p^n)$ and both $p^n$ and $p^{n+1}$ are in $(p^n)$. So I guess what confuses me is the word "either". Or maybe $p^np^{n+1}=pp^{2n}$ and now $p$ is not in $(p^n)$ and $p^{2n}$ is.

In terms of numbers, take the ideal $(4)$ in the ring of integers, book says it's primary. Now $32\in(4),\ 32=4\times 8,\ 4\in(4)\text{ and } 8\in (4)$, so no "either". How do I interpret this particular definition?

Comment: You can interpret the definition as: $q$ is a primary ideal of a ring $R$ if, for any $x,y\in R$ with $x\notin q$, $xy\in q$ implies $y^n\in q$ for some $n$

Comment: "either A or B" means the same thing as "A or B" in English. To make it mutually exclusive you'd say something like "A or B but not both"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "either" part of the definition means that **at least one** of the statements is true. To further clarify, it might be the case that one statement is false (like $p \notin q$ in your example) but the other statement is true (like $p^{2n} \in q$). Further, it is also possible for both statements to be true simultaneously because, again, we only require at least one statement to be true. Your example at the end of your post is such an example.

It might be helpful to also consider when an ideal is not primary. In order to show that an ideal is not primary, we need to prove $xy \in I$ but $x\notin I$ **and** $y^n \notin I$ for all $n$. That is, we need to show that the statement $x \in q$ and $y^n \in q$ for some $n$ are both simultaneously false.

Somewhat related, sometimes the "or" can be ambiguous without context. For example, an integer can either be even or odd. One of these statements is true but it's certainly not the case that both are simultaneously true about an integer. Other times, like in the definition of primary ideals, the "or" means "at least one." So context is important when an "or" statement is involved. One way to help distinguish which "or" is meant in a mathematical result if context doesn't help is to create examples, like you have.

Comment: Ok, I thought it meant one or the other and not both. So basically we can omit the word "either" and use the basic logics meaning of "or"?

Comment: @Algebear Yes, that's right. If by "basic logic meaning of or" you mean the truth table for the "or" operator, then yes, that's right too.